# forEach over cursor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm using a nested function to call two methods to duplicate a set of documents.  The documents come from two different collections but are linked in by the treeBranches field, as shown below.

**Trees collection**

```
{ 
    _id: "tree_1", 
    treeBranches: ["branch_1","branch_2"], 
    ... 
}
```

**Branches collection**

```
{ 
    _id: "branch_1", 
    branchName: "Branch 1", 
    ... 
}
{ 
    _id: "branch_2", 
    branchName: "Branch 2", 
    ... 
}
```

I don't understand how to get the `_id` of each existing branch document within `branches.forEach`.  Right now, when I run this, multiple branch documents are created, but each duplicates the first existing branch regardless of how many exist.  How can I edit `var currentBranchId = Branches.findOne({})._id;` to get this `_id` and properly loop over the set?

CODE EDITED TO INCORPORATE ANSWER

```
    Template.Actions.events({
    'change .action-selection': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var selection = $(e.target).val();

        var currentTreeId = this._id;
        var branches = Branches.find({_id:{$in:this.treeBranches}});

        switch(selection) {
            case "tree-repeat":
                return Meteor.call('treeRepeat', currentTreeId, function () {
                    branches.forEach(function(b) {
                        var currentBranchId = b._id; 
                        Meteor.call('treeBranchesRepeat', currentBranchId, function (branchId) {
                        });
                    });
                });
                break;
                …
            }
        }
    });

    Meteor.methods({
        treeRepeat: function(currentTreeId) {
            check(currentTreeId, String);

        var tree = Trees.findOne({_id:currentTreeId}, {fields:{_id:0, treeBranches:0}});

        var treeExtended = _.extend(tree, {
            treeBranches: [?]//NEED IDS FROM NEW BRANCHES
        });

        var treeId = Trees.insert(treeExtended);

            return {
                _id: treeId
            };
        },
        treeBranchesRepeat: function(currentBranchId) {
            check(currentBranchId, String);

            var branch = Branches.findOne({_id:currentBranchId}, {fields: {_id: 0}});

            var branchId = Branches.insert(branch);

            return {
                _id: branchId
            };
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over a cursor with `forEach` (just like an array) so, for example:

```
var cursor = Branches.find();
cursor.forEach(function(b){ // b will be a single branch document
  console.log(b._id); // you can get its _id directly
  console.log(b.branchName); // or any other key
});
```

It makes no sense to do a `forEach()` over a cursor and then do a `findOne` inside the loop since `forEach()` will pass each object in turn to the anonymous function.

It's not clear from your question how you decide which branches belong to which tree.

If I wanted to create a denormalized copy of your original `Trees` collection I might do the following:

```
var treeCursor = Trees.find();
treeCursor.forEach(function(tree){
  DenormalizedTrees.insert({_id: tree._id}); // reuse the same _id
  tree.treeBranches.forEach(function(id){ // now iterate over the array of branch ids
    var branch = Branches.findOne(id);
    DenormalizedTrees.update(tree._id,{ $push: { treeBranches: branch }});
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Michel, halfway there - you solved my first problem with `(b)` - I didn't know I could use that without further defining which doc it was.  As for your question, the branches that belong with each tree are the ones whose ids exist in the `treeBranches` array.  Using the first part of your solution, I have now been able to create a duplicate version of the tree and both branches.  But I need to pass the _id created for each branch from the inner function to the outer function to add to treeBranches in the new tree. I can't do it in the inner function since the new tree doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't believe I need the second block of code, since 1) I know which tree I am duplicating and 2) I am duplicating all documents within their existing collections, but with new ids.

Comment: Thanks Michel, I'm going to post a separate question on passing between functions as I think I am combining too many points here.

Comment: Thanks @Bren, I think that will be better.